# What is radius_mean() in this histogram

Tags: data-visualization

I was trying to plot a histogram for no of Malignant vs benign tumors.
Here is the kaggle kernel I am practising from:https://www.kaggle.com/kanncaa1/basic-statistic-tutorial-for-beginners

However, I dont understand what is radius_mean here.
Without it, it is throwing an error.

```
    m = plt.hist(data[data["diagnosis"] == "M"].radius_mean,bins=30,fc= (1,0,0,0.5),label = "Malignant")
    b = plt.hist(data[data["diagnosis"] == "B"].radius_mean,bins=30,fc = (0,1,0,0.5),label = "Bening")
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel("Radius Mean Values")
    plt.ylabel("Frequency")
    plt.title("Histogram of Radius Mean for Bening and Malignant Tumors")
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

radius_mean is a feature in your data set.

What the codes does is to plot the histogram of the radius mean of the data that are classified as benign and malign separately.

Comment: yes. I figured it 10 seconds ago. Just getting started with stats & it is so confusing. i am so dumb. Thanks though